# Kali.download website blocked by Kaspersky because of Trojan, is it safe?

Tags: antivirus, kali-linux, trojan

So when I tried to `dist upgrade` my Kali, at the end my Antivirus blocked it from downloading from this website

Do all Kali Linux operating systems try to download from this webpage (http://kali.download) or something malicious is going on?

Is it safe to turn off my Antivirus and continue downloading?

Why does Kaspersky think there is a Trojan in this link?  This is the error:

```
Download blocked;
http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/m/mimikatz/mimikatz_2.1.1-20180925-0kali1_all.deb//data.tar.xz//data.tar//./usr/share/mimikatz/Win32/mimidrv.sys;
Trojan-PSW.Win32.Mimikatz.gen;http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/m/mimikatz/mimikatz_2.1.1-20180925-0kali1_all.deb//data.tar.xz//data.tar//./usr/share/mimikatz/Win32/mimidrv.sys;
VMware NAT Service;
Trojan program;10/13/2018  


Object-name : Trojan-PSW.Win32.Mimikatz.gen
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kali has many tools that are legitimately malicious tools. So, it is not surprising that Anti-Virus would detect and block those tools.

Mimikatz (the thing you listed as being blocked) is a tool on Kali and is a very powerful malicious tool.

kali.download is an official mirror:
https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/download-speed-issues/

We also cannot say if turning off your Anti-Virus is a safe. But what it is detecting is expected and normal for what you are downloading.

Comment: Thanks for answer But 1. do all the people who use Kali Linux and try to upgrade go to this kali.download or just me? is it an official website?!  and 2. then what should i do now? not upgrade my kali linux ever or is there a solution?

Comment: I also downloaded this from the Kali official website and its the VMware image, and i checked the hash of the downloaded file and it matches their website, but I'm still not sure if this link is safe and do all Kali users go to this when they upgrade or not

Comment: I really don't think kali.download is official website but if you want to upgrade then just download it from their official site or in terminal `apt update && apt -y full-upgrade`